# Using comonadicity to prove faithfully flat descent

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, descent

I have heard many times that faithfully flat descent could be reinterpreted via Beck's monadicity theorem; Deligne's paper "Catégories tannakiennes" even explains in section 4 how to do this for affine schemes. However, I have been struggling to implement this in the non-affine case.

Specifically, I want to prove that if $f : X\to S$ is a quasicompact, faithfully flat morphism of schemes, then there is an equivalence of categories between quasicoherent sheaves on $S$ and quasicoherent sheaves on $X$ with descent data.

Modelling Deligne's argument in the affine case, one can start by saying we have this faithful exact functor $f^* : \operatorname{Qcoh}(S) \to \operatorname{Qcoh}(X),$ with a right adjoint $f_{\sharp} : \operatorname{Qcoh}(X)\to \operatorname{Qcoh}(S)$ (I did not know that $f^*$ generally had a right adjoint at the quasicoherent level; see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3665838 for example if you also did not know this--I'm unsure how standard this is so I felt it worth noting).

This adjunction is comonadic by Barr-Beck, and so the problem becomes explaining why coalgebras over the comonad associated to this adjunction (sending $\mathcal{F}$ to $f^*f_{\sharp}\mathcal{F}$) are equivalent to descent data.

The key point of this argument seems to be verifying that a coevaluation map $\mathcal{F} \to f^{\ast}f_{\sharp}\mathcal{F}$ is equivalent to a map $\pi_1^{\ast}\mathcal{F}\to\pi_2^*\mathcal{F},$ for $\pi_1, \pi_2 : X\times_S X\to X$ the two projections. This in turn seems to boil down to asking the base change map $f^{\ast}f_{\sharp}\mathcal{F} \to \pi_{1,\sharp}\pi_2^{\ast}\mathcal{F}$ (although, unless I'm mistaken, the quasicompactness hypothesis on $f$ implies that $\pi_1$ is qcqs and so $\pi_{1,\sharp} = \pi_{1,\ast}$) is an isomorphism. However, I cannot seem to show this is actually an isomorphism.

This seems to be well-known, but I can't find a reference anywhere that explains this point. I'm probably missing something elementary, so hopefully someone here can explain how to prove this equivalence of categories between coalgebras and descent datum!

Comment: I am not sure, but the below reference might be useful --- there a descent theory, based on Beck's monadicity is developed for derived categories. Elagin, A. D. Cohomological descent theory for a morphism of stacks and for equivariant derived categories. (Russian) ; translated from Mat. Sb. 202 (2011), no. 4, 31--64 Sb. Math. 202 (2011), no. 3-4, 495--526.

Comment: You may try to see how local is your problem. Prove that, for an open cover of $S$ by open subschemes $U$, if what you want to prove is true for $f^{-1}(V)\to V$ then it is true for $f$. Similarly, if you cover $X$ by open subschemes $U$ such that what you want is true for the map $U\to f(U)$, then it is true for $f$ (you might have to use that flat maps are open). Hence you will reduce to the affine case.

Comment: The link between descent and monadicity sometimes goes by the name of the Bénabou–Roubaud theorem; see for instance the [nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/B%C3%A9nabou-Roubaud%20theorem) for motivation and references.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I've tried such ideas, but at least I was unable to get them to work -- part of it is that I have trouble manipulating $f_{\sharp},$ and part is that fpqc descent needs the qc condition and I am unsure how to incorporate that usefully

Comment: @MichaelBarz What you call $f_\sharp$ is usually denoted by $f_*$. And a useful trick is to check that, for any open $V$ of $S$, the restriction of $f_*(F)$ to $V$ is canonically isomorphic to $g_*(G)$ where $G$ is the restriction of $F$ to $f^{-1}(V)$ and $g$ is the restriction of $f$ to $f^{-1}(V)$, seen as a map to $V$.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I thought $f_*$ was reserved for the adjoint functor at the level of sheaves of modules; here I am using this adjoint at the level of quasicoherents, which is in general a different functor than $f_*$ if I am not mistaken, and it seems people do not denote this one by $f_*.$ I know of the property you refer of for $f_*,$ but I was unsure if it also held for $f_{\sharp}.$